# How to retrieve hashtags from MongoDB Array of Strings?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have saved hashtags as an array of Strings. Saved in MongoDB in the following format:

```
const postSchema = new Schema {
  name:{type: String},
  tags: {type: [String], required: true}
});
```

I want to retrieve a list of tags from my database. The following route returns all tags by scanning all posts:

```
Post.find({}, 'tags').exec(function(err,tags){
    res.send({tags});
}
```

But that includes a lot of repetition and isn't a clean list. As well as takes a lot of time to load because I have a lot of posts.

Is there a better way to retrieve hashtags? I'm thinking of saving hashtags as a new Schema modal and just referencing them to the post schema.

Comment: Please share input data and output data at jso editor online